# Why does this code execute instantly when I add in Promise code?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

In the code below I would expect two 4 second delays.  But if you run the code you will see it executes instantly.  Obviously I don't understand something very fundamental or I am a stupid error I can't see.

```js
function calculatesomething(resolve) {
  console.log("calculating");

  setTimeout(results(resolve,3),4000);
}

var answer=0;
function results(resolve,n) {
  console.log("got results");

  answer=1;
  resolve(answer+n);
}



function doingstuff() {
  console.log("starting");

  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(calculatesomething(resolve),4000);
  });

  promise1.then(function(value) {
    console.log("done: "+value);
  });

  console.log("regular execution");
}

doingstuff();
```

(sorry about the indenting here.  I have no idea why its not respecting the tabs.)

Answer (score 6):

The very fundamental thing is this:

```
 setTimeout(results(resolve,3),4000);
```

You dont need to call the function directly and pass the returned value, but rather pass the function reference:

```
 setTimeout(results, 4000, /*args:*/ resolve, 4);
```

Comment: TIL you can pass the parameters in with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Pretty elegant solution, upvote

Comment: @derek just spent 10 minutes each in writing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780927/javascript-when-and-when-not-to-use-this/48790252#48790252) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794471/general-solution-for-pre-emptive-background-work-scheduling-on-javascript/48795175#48795175) answer and i get 5 upvotes for such a common mistake, that is well documented everywhere... :/ And you didnt know this? That surprises me...

Comment: @commercial suicide thanks :)

Comment: @JonasW. Even as an experienced developer, JavaScript still gives me surprises every now and then ;)

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` accepts a callback function as first parameter and one of possible solutions will be to wrap your function invocation inside an anonymous function like this:

```js
function calculatesomething(resolve) {
  console.log("calculating");

  setTimeout(function() {
    results(resolve,3);
  }, 4000)
}

var answer=0;
function results(resolve,n) {
  console.log("got results");

  answer=1;
  resolve(answer+n);
}



function doingstuff() {
  console.log("starting");

  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      calculatesomething(resolve)
    }, 4000);
  });

  promise1.then(function(value) {
    console.log("done: "+value);
  });
        
  console.log("regular execution");
}

doingstuff();
```

Comment: Wow it works now!!  I will study this more to understand.  I have used setTimeout many times without this problem.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1254723, cheers!

Comment: `Jonas W. provided more elegant way, I upvote him, but my example is working too, but not so elegant.` :) ... i appreciate that, however this is not really mandatory just saying...

Comment: @Jonas W., got it, the answer is updated =)